# Difference between source code hosted on Android Code Search and on Git repos on android.googlesource.com?

Tags: android, android-source, code-search

I'm trying to understand the difference between the two resources:

Android Code Search - https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:;bpv=0
and
Git repositories on android - https://android.googlesource.com/

To add to the confusion I also see this repo on Github - https://github.com/androidx/androidx

What is the purpose of all of the above? Is there any substantial difference between the code hosted on each one of those?

Thanks in advance,
Roman

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in the code found on these sites.

- the github.com AOSP/AndroidX repos are used as a mirror for AOSP code
- cs.android.com is a code browser for AOSP/AndroidX code
- android.googlesource.com is the official public location for AOSP code which can be cloned as described at https://source.android.com/docs/setup/download/downloading